# Apply theme on login screen

Tags: 18.04, themes, login-screen

I've installed the popular `arc-theme` (with gnome-tweaks) and it looks awesome in the darker variant. However it does not load until I log in. I would like to have it applied to the login screen as well (top bar, buttons, backgrounds), how can I do that?

Comment: Hi, Can you go through this Q & A https://askubuntu.com/q/1064491/739431

Comment: @PRATAP yes I found that but it shows how to manually modify it. I'd like to just have the theme applied and the theme doesn't seem to have a gdm3 file that I can just swap

Comment: Hi, in my recent trails i found a way to achieve this. can you share the `arc-theme` link, so that i will test it and then post as answer. Thanks

Comment: @PRATAP https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme or just `sudo apt install arc-theme`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for Arc-Theme, in Ubuntu 18.04.

[Ubuntu 18.04 change Login Screen theme (not wallpaper)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1064491/739431) following this Answer and Warnings in it.

I have tried to change login & lock screen themes same as `User Shell` Theme `Arc-Theme`

[image]

when you download the arc-theme from https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme github.
simplfy it like below

[image]

this Arc-Theme is lacking content for some keys for Onscreen-Keyboard.

so, i have adapted that from default file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

[image]

copy the lines 1549 to 1566 from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` and paste under line number 1708 in `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Theme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`

```
  .keyboard-key.default-key {
    border-color: #32322d;
    background-color: #20201d;
    background-size: 20px; }
  .keyboard-key.enter-key {
    border-color: #dd4814;
    background-color: #e95420;
    background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/key-enter.svg"); }
  .keyboard-key.shift-key-lowercase {
    background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/key-shift.svg"); }
  .keyboard-key.shift-key-uppercase {
    background-image: url("key-shift-uppercase.svg"); }
  .keyboard-key.shift-key-uppercase:latched {
    background-image: url("key-shift-latched-uppercase.svg"); }
  .keyboard-key.hide-key {
    background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/key-hide.svg"); }
  .keyboard-key.layout-key {
    background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/key-layout.svg"); }
```

save the file & close.

now run the below command:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css && sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Arc-Theme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ sudo rm /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css && sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Arc-Theme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css
[sudo] password for pratap: 
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

now copy the 3 folders **common-assets, dark-assets & light-assets** from `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Theme/gnome-shell/` to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`

[image]

now copy paste all the content from `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Theme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file replacing the data in ubuntu.css file.

save the file, close & shutdown

fresh start the system to see the change.

Lock Screen animation:
[image]

Login Screen Pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm only worried about potential issues during future package upgrades...

Comment: Ok.. then keep the arc theme folder in `.themes` folder instead of `/usr/share/themes/` and follow the same stpes

Answer (score 3):

Actually just figure out the proper way to do this today by adding options to `update-alternatives`.

First, you can view the current setting of `gdm3.css` using

```
update-alternatives --display gdm3.css
```

You should see the following text.

```
gdm3.css - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css
  link currently points to /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css
  link gdm3.css is /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css - priority 15
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css - priority 10
```

I have installed the Adapta themes, and I would like to add Adapta-Eta theme to the options for gdm3.css. The path of the `gdm3.css` for Adapta-Eta theme is `/usr/share/themes/Adapta-Eta/gnome-shell/gdm3-Adapta-Eta.css`.

To install the Adapta-Eta `gdm3.css`,

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css gdm3.css /usr/share/themes/Adapta-Eta/gnome-shell/gdm3-Adapta-Eta.css 20
```

> `update-alternatives --install link name path priority`
>
> you should use the `link gdm3.css is ...` from the text you get using the `--display` option as **link**.
>
> **name** should be `gdm3.css`
>
> **path** is the path to the new option
>
> you can set any integer for **priority** (I don't know what difference it makes)

Now to change the theme of the login screen, use
`sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

Choose the new theme you want to use. You should be able to see the change after reboot.

I'm not sure if the upgrade of the system will modify it, but at least when the theme is updated it would be overridden.

Although this is one issue, the lock screen appears to not changing according to the choice. Only the login screen follows the choice.