# Difference between gnome-shell.css and ubuntu.css, and what are they for?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, gnome-shell, css

In `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`, I had amended `#lockDialogGroup{}` to try to show an image in the GDM and made changes to `/* Auth Dialogs & Screen Shield */` to change the locking appearance. However, I discovered that these changes did not take effect. Instead, I had to implement the changes to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` to see their effect.

Am I correct to conclude from these observations that:

1. `ubuntu.css` is used to control the style of the GNOME Display Manager(Login screen) while `gnome-shell.css` is used to control the style of the Desktop? If so, why does `gnome-shell.css` also contain a section on `#lockDialogGroup{}` and `/* Auth Dialogs & Screen Shield */` as they seem redundant?
2. Would I be able to override `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` with my own `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`?
3. I would like to change the font size of clock shown in the lock screen and the duration for showing the lock screen (I find it disappears too quickly). Which file do I use to implement changes and which variable do I need to change?

This question is a continuation from what I learnt from [my earlier question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174806/can-local-share-gnome-shell-theme-ubuntu-css-have-priority-over-usr-share/1174840?noredirect=1#comment1961258_1174840)

Comment: @PRATAP Yes. Chosen by GNOME Tweaks -->Appearance -->Shell.

Comment: @PRATAP I like to understand the diff between gnome-shell.css and ubuntu.css, their use, why they contain same variables when they don't all seem to be used and how to customize the lockscreen clock per my question.

Comment: this may give you a clue https://askubuntu.com/q/1087016/739431 https://askubuntu.com/q/1064491/739431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ubuntu.css is used to control the style of the GNOME Display
>   Manager(Login screen) while gnome-shell.css is used to control the
>   style of the Desktop? If so, why does gnome-shell.css also contain a
>   section on #lockDialogGroup{} and /* Auth Dialogs & Screen Shield */
>   as they seem redundant?

This Assumption is wrong.. you can use any valid file as login-screen theme, unlock-screen theme and for the user-theme

> Would I be able to override /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
>   with my own
>   ~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css?

you can use any valid file as a User-Theme selected via Gnome-Tweaks

> I would like to change the font size of clock shown in the lock screen
>   and the duration for showing the lock screen (I find it disappears too
>   quickly). Which file do I use to implement changes and which variable
>   do I need to change?

These are two different questions, which are already asked in this forum.. you can get them with deep searching in AskUbuntu itself...

---

In a fresh Install of Ubuntu 18.04,

If you observe the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "ubuntu.css",
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com"]
}
```

the line `stylesheeName: ubuntu.css` indicates that the default-shell theme (i.e when no `user-theme` gnome-shell-extension is installed) uses the theme file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

and the background you will have in this file, uses for the unlock-screen background

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
```

---

The Login-Screen Background uses the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

you can check which file is used for login-screen theme with the below command

`sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

```
pratap@pratap:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
[sudo] password for pratap: 
There is only one alternative in link group gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css): /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
Nothing to configure.
pratap@pratap:~$
```

If you notice above two cases.. in a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 `ubuntu.css` file is used for both unlock-screen theming and login-screen theming..

Both are configurable to your choices..

I always have different themes for login-screen and lock-screen.. for the running desktop select the theme from User-Themes via gnome-tweaks..

So, you can have different themes for `login-screen`, `unlock-screen` and for the regular desktop.. but in a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 all these 3 are configured to use `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file..

---

***Warning: editing shell theme files are very risky.. small mistakes will break the shell, If you know how to revert the changes via tty, then only proceed..***

take backup of the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` first

then edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

find the below content and adjust the font-sizes as you want..

```
.screen-shield-clock-time {
  font-size: 72pt;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

.screen-shield-clock-date {
  font-size: 28pt;
  font-weight: normal; }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without amending `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`, presently, I discovered that I can amend the lock-screen background by using `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri file:///home/user/Pictures/myimage.jpg`. Why is this the case?

Comment: With `user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` enabled, can I use `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/ubuntu.css` to override  `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`?

Comment: With user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com enabled, do you mean to say I can use `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` to override `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`? I had tried this earlier but it did not work. I still had to use `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` to change background of login screen and unlock screen.

Comment: I have done that. Hence my questions. Can you instead answer the 3 questions I have posted above with the view that `user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` is enabled. I got the fresh Install of Ubuntu 18.04 part. I now have my own theme in  ~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css. Can I use it to change appearance of Login screen, and Unlock screen too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98824/discussion-between-sun-bear-and-pratap).

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, I found out that `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css` actually links back to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`. Hence to configure the clock font size in the lock screen, I have to change *font-size* and *font-weight* for *.screen-shield-clock-time* class in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` and not `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` even though `user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` is enabled.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted clarity on. You wrote "you can use any valid file as a User-Theme selected via Gnome-Tweaks" in your answer for Q2, which seems incorrect (confusing me) given that only changes in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` can change the features of the lockscreen. With `user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` enabled, `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` can only be used to controls the features of the Desktop (Not Login Screen, Lock screen and Unlock screen). Appreciate your help. ;)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347926/how-do-i-customize-gnome-screen-shield-curtain-login-screen-appearance Answer to Q3

Comment: In case you are able to find how to control the duration for showing the lock screen (it is too short for now), please do let me know. thank you.